# How would I have test code to test if an input has characters instead of numbers

Tags: java, numbers, logic

```
public void deposit (double amount){
    if (amount >= 0) {
    balance = balance + amount;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your deposit is a negative number, If you would like to withdraw please enter '0' and select Withdraw.");
    }
        while (!double || !int) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again");
        }
    }
```

This is the code, I am trying to get to test whether or not a user input entered in another class file has a character other than an integer or double. I need for this piece of code to work here and with a withdraw class that I have already created underneath this one, I figured if it I can get it to work in one it will work in the other. 
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code Requested:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bank {
double balance = 0;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int userChoice;
BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount();
boolean quit = false; {
do {
System.out.println("Your Choice: ");
System.out.println("For Deposit type 1");
System.out.println("For Withdraw type 2");
System.out.println("For Check Balance type 3");
System.out.println("Type 0 to quit");
userChoice = in.nextInt();
switch (userChoice){
case 1: 

    //Deposit Money
    System.out.println("How Much would you like to deposit?");
    double amount;
    amount = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Depositing: " + amount);
    account1.deposit(amount);
    //balance = amount + balance;
    break;
case 2: 
    //Withdraw money
    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
    amount = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Withdrawing: " + amount);
    account1.withdraw(amount);
    //balance = balance - amount;
    break;
case 3: 
    //check balance
    System.out.println("Checking Balance.");
    account1.getBalance();

    System.out.println(account1.balance);
    break;
case 0: 
    System.out.println("Thanks for Using BankAccount Banking System!");
    quit = true;
    break;
default: 
    System.out.println("Error: Choice not recognized please choose again.");
    continue;
}

if (userChoice ==  0)
    quit = true;
}while 
(!quit);
}
}
```

And here is the entirety of the first portion of code:

```
public class BankAccount {

public double balance;
public int sufficientFunds = 1;
public int insufficientFunds = -1;

public BankAccount(){
    balance = 0;
}


public BankAccount (double initialBalance){
    balance = initialBalance;
}


public void deposit (double amount){
    if (amount >= 0) {
    balance = balance + amount;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your deposit is a negative number, If you would like to withdraw please enter '0' and select Withdraw.");
    }
        while (!double || !int) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again");
        }
    }



public double withdraw (double amount){
    balance = balance - amount;

    if (balance == amount){
        return sufficientFunds;
    }else if (balance > amount){
        return sufficientFunds;
    }else if (balance < amount){
        System.out.println("INSUFFICENT FUNDS");
        return insufficientFunds;
    }
    return amount;

}


public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}
```

}

Comment: This is not Java at all... especially the while 'loop'. Can you show us the code calling this code?

Comment: Which "input entered in another class"?

Comment: @RudolphEst That is java. I think OP used !double || !int to tell us what's supposed to go in the while loop condition signifying that they want a condition which returns true when amount is not a double or int variable.

Comment: I added the rest of the code that I have.  and @MarkSaidCamilleri yes that is what I was going for.

Comment: The accepted answer is actually a bad example. This is not how validations should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a strongly typed language, so there is no chance that the amount variable could contain anything other than a double, which is a number.

Comment: smart pick . I was typing up a solution :) . Spot on +1

Comment: I basically just need it to produce an error message from me rather than the Java IDE that I am using (Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so when accepting the input for `amount`, surround it with a try-catch block so that instead of simply

```
amount = in.nextDouble();
```

you'll get

```
try{
    amount = in.nextDouble();
}catch(InputMismatchException ime){
    //What to do if this is not a numerical value
}
```

Additionally you'll want to wrap that in a do-while loop so that the program asks again until a valid input is accepted:

```
boolean inputInvalid;
double amount;
do{
    System.out.println("How Much would you like to deposit?");
    try{
        amount = in.nextDouble();
        inputInvalid = false;
    }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
        //What to do if this is not a numerical value
        inputInvalid = true;
    }
}while(inputInvalid);
```

---

**Edit**: due to the `in.nextDouble()`, the program may be continuously trying to read the `\n` in the buffer (which is when the user presses `Enter`). To avoid this, right after initializing the `Scanner` object (or first thing in a method if it's a class variable), add

```
in.useDelimiter("\n");
```

To the Java to end the input at that and ignore the newline character.

Comment: Ok I Implemented this, however when an incorrect input is entered this loops continuously printing over and over again the error.  would I include a 'break;' statement after the while portion to stop this? in other words it is not pausing for the next input to be taken, it is just looping the print statements

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I forgot about the problem regarding Scanner. It's a really common issue. See edit for the solution to that.

Comment: I added that, and now it stopped the whole program with this exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
 Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
 Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration

 at Bank.<init>(Bank.java:8)
 at BankRunner.main(BankRunner.java:5) also all these errors are coming from the statement in.useDelimiter("\n);

Comment: Did you add it in a method? I just noticed that `in` is a class variable (so I edited the edit to reflect that you need to add the like for the delimiter in a method). Also, did you write it as `"\n"`?

Comment: `boolean inputInvalid = false;
  in.useDelimiter("\n");
  do{
  System.out.println("How Much would you like to deposit?");
  try{
   amount = in.nextDouble();
   
  }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
   System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again");
   inputInvalid = true;
  }
  }while (inputInvalid);
  
  System.out.println("Depositing: " + amount);
  account1.deposit(amount);
  //balance = amount + balance;
  break;` This is the code I have and how I implemented the delimiter statement

Comment: and it is still overly repeating except now the user doesn't even get the option to input anything.

Comment: My mistake, under `amount = in.next double();` there should be `inputInvalid = false;`. Also the delimiter line must come before any Scanner input done by `in`, before the line accepting the input for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for bank

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank {
    double balance = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userChoice;
    BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount();
    boolean quit = false;
    public void thisShouldBeAMethod(){
        do {
            System.out.println("Your Choice: ");
            System.out.println("For Deposit type 1");
            System.out.println("For Withdraw type 2");
            System.out.println("For Check Balance type 3");
            System.out.println("Type 0 to quit");
            //userChoice = in.nextInt();
            String regex = "[0-9]+";
            String input = in.next(); 
            if(input.matches(regex)){
                userChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);
                switch (userChoice) {
                case 1:

                    // Deposit Money
                    System.out.println("How Much would you like to deposit?");
                    double amount;
                    amount = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Depositing: " + amount);
                    account1.deposit(amount);
                    // balance = amount + balance;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Withdraw money
                    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                    amount = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Withdrawing: " + amount);
                    account1.withdraw(amount);
                    // balance = balance - amount;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // check balance
                    System.out.println("Checking Balance.");
                    account1.getBalance();

                    System.out.println(account1.balance);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out
                            .println("Thanks for Using BankAccount Banking System!");
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out
                            .println("Error: Choice not recognized please choose again.");
                    continue;
                }

                if (userChoice == 0)
                    quit = true;
            }
            else{
                 System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again");
            }

        } while (!quit);
    }
}
```

update this in BankAccount

```
public void deposit (double amount){
        if (amount >= 0) {
        balance = balance + amount;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your deposit is a negative number, If you would like to withdraw please enter '0' and select Withdraw.");
        }
//          while (!double || !int) {
//              System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again");
//          }
        }
```

And test

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank bank = new Bank();
        bank.thisShouldBeAMethod();
    }


}
```